# Xcode Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I currently have an app published on the App Store but I've just updated it to support native iPad usage as well. Obviously when doing this I had to create a new Development profile for the app to support both my iPhone and iPad for testing. However my question is do I have to create a new Distribution Profile too or is the current one fine?

There doesn't seem to be an option for iPhone or iPad specific profiles but I noticed in Xcode when I switch the App Build Settings for being Development to Distribution it still says

```
iPhone Distribution current matches "iPhone Distribution **NAME OF PROFILE**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution certificates are basically connected to your App store account. You only have one presence for distribution (I assume) so one distribution profile is all that is needed.

Short answer - The current profile is fine.